# how seed method use foreach loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
 protected override void Seed(ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext context)
  {
      var students = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student { FirstMidName = "Carson",   LastName = "Alexander", 
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2010-09-01") },
            new Student { FirstMidName = "Meredith", LastName = "Alonso",    
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-09-01") },
            new Student { FirstMidName = "Arturo",   LastName = "Anand",     
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-09-01") },
            new Student { FirstMidName = "Gytis",    LastName = "Barzdukas", 
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-09-01") },
            new Student { FirstMidName = "Yan",      LastName = "Li",        
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-09-01") },
            new Student { FirstMidName = "Peggy",    LastName = "Justice",   
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-09-01") },
            new Student { FirstMidName = "Laura",    LastName = "Norman",    
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-09-01") },
            new Student { FirstMidName = "Nino",     LastName = "Olivetto",  
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2005-08-11") }
        };
     students.ForEach(s => context.Students.AddOrUpdate(p => p.LastName, s));
     context.SaveChanges();
```

I am using migration in my MVC project but In Configuration.cs file in above code. used seed method but i do not understand the syntax of Foreach loop .so any one can suggest me.

Comment: This is `ForEach` and not `foreach`. It is `List.ForEach` and not general `foreach` iteration statement.

Comment: rewritten, that line of code would be `foreach(var s in students)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The List.ForEach method is like 'foreach' loop. It uses a lambda to performs the action on each element.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx